# Rails 4 and Foundation 5 - Sticky Footer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sticky-footer, zurb-foundation-5

So I was using static pages until I decided to migrate over to Rails for use in my web app.

I was able to effectively create a sticky footer with the following codePen:

http://codepen.io/aetles/pen/jAdzw

```
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

window.onload = function() {
  stickyFooter();
};

function checkForDOMChange() {
  stickyFooter();
}
//check for resize event if not IE 9 or greater
window.onresize = function() {
  stickyFooter();
}
//lets get the marginTop for the <footer>
function getCSS(element, property) {

  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName(element)[0];
  var css = null;
  if (elem.currentStyle) {
    css = elem.currentStyle[property];
  } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
  css = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null).
  getPropertyValue(property);
  }
  return css;
}

function stickyFooter() {
  console.log("sticky footer is firing");
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].getAttribute("style") != null) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].removeAttribute("style");
  } 
  if (window.innerHeight != document.body.offsetHeight) {
    var offset = window.innerHeight - document.body.offsetHeight;
    var current = getCSS("footer", "margin-top");
    if (isNaN(current) == true) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].setAttribute("style","margin-top:0px;");
      current = 0;
    } else {
      current = parseInt(current);
    }
    if (current+offset > parseInt(getCSS("footer", "margin-top"))) {      
      document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].setAttribute("style","margin-top:"+(current+offset)+"px;");
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I deploy it into a real-time application utilizing Rails, the event itself is getting fired (I tested with console.log messages) but it doesn't actually edit the position of the footer.

(view console in the following page)
https://still-plains-7660.herokuapp.com/

Because I'm using a partial for the footer itself, could it be that Rails doesn't know what to actually move? The source code on the rendered page looks as it should.

Is there a more elegant gem or solution I can utilize to have a sticky footer that does *not* have a fixed height? (I need it responsive).

Considering it works fine on a static page, I'm sure there is something I can just tweak but I can't seem to figure out why it won't stick in a Rails deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot remember what exactly I did when I created sticky footer using Foundation. But I think I found some solution for you.

- https://github.com/coreysyms/foundationStickyFooter
- http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/629-sticky-footer